# Where (address) is the PES data fpr GAL20V8 devices?

Tags: fpga

I am looking for information on the PES (Programmers Electronic Signature) for GAL devices.

I found some information about how to interpret the data, yet it is not clear to me where the data is located. By this, I mean at what address.

If I read the entire contents, how do I know where the PES is located?

For the GAL20V8 I believe it to be from 2568 to 2631. On my parts, mass programmed for my former employer, those bits appear to be programmed with their company's part number, rather then the programming parameters as I'd hoped.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, so questions are not the start of a chat - they should be detailed enough to get a single answer. People here will help you take the next step if your question describes your problem in detail and shows you've already done as much as you possibly could. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Explain your problem, show your own work and own findings in considerable detail. Which GALs? The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: your post is based on a false belief that the signature bits come preconfigured from factory ... it is your job to program them with data that is meaningful to you ... there is nothing for you to interpret

Comment: See this, it may perhaps help you : http://matthieu.benoit.free.fr/ST_GAL_devices_programmer.htm There is a software for programming these devices, so perhaps some infos you need.